# Best way to use Fragments

Tags: android-fragments, fragmentmanager

There are a lot of answers of this questions but technically my question is different, I've read some documentation and agreed we should not use multiple fragments in only one activity , we should use multiple activities with multiple fragments depend on project requirement or UI specification , 
so architecture of my application is 
1. BaseActivity and all activities extends from that
2. BaseFragment and all Fragments extends from that 
my Code:

in BaseActivity I've made following functions

```
public void replaceFragment(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag);
    if(addToBackStack)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
    if(fragmentTag.matches("") && addToBackStack)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

To Add Fragment in Framelayout

```
public void addFragment(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String fragmentTag, boolean addToBackStack, boolean isPending) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment, fragmentTag);
    if(addToBackStack)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
    if(fragmentTag.matches("") && addToBackStack)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    if(isPending)
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
}
```

Back Press Functionality

```
public void popBackStackImmediate() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

Get Total Fragments

```
public List<Fragment> fragmentList(){
    return getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
}
```

and the flow is 
FragmentA (add) -> FragmentB (replace) ->

QUETSION 1 : why totalFragments are showing 2 ? while I've replaced FragmentB to A

QUESTION 2: when i press back button still showing 2 Fragments and how may i remove from stack ?

Question 3: FragmentB is visible but FragmentA fragment life cycle working too ..means onResume and onCreate funcations are calling too strange but true dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: You have not removed any fragment therefore the fragment count is 2. When you replace a fragment, you are replacing it in the fragment container, not it's instance.

Question 2: Once you add a fragment to the backstack, it means you will navigate back to it once you hit the back button. Still, your fragment manager fragment count will still be 2 since no fragment was removed. If you want to remove it the following code will do the trick:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(yourFragment).commit();
```

Question 3: Once you replace fragment A with fragment B, fragment A will still be active and will call it's `onPause`, `onDestroy` and `onDestroyView`, if you bring it back to the container it starts it's lifecycle from `onCreateView`, that meaning that running `onResume` is normal, however `onCreate` is not.